# Android: Setting the Zoom for the Map Intent

Tags: android, dictionary

Java or .NET answers are fine.

I create an Android Map with the following, works fine:

```
   var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("geo:42.374260,-71.120824");
   var mapIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, geoUri);
   StartActivity (mapIntent);
```

Is there a way to send the intent a request to zoom to a certain amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html add suffix "?z=zoom" where zoom is from [2..23]

Answer (score 0):

"geo:42.374260,-71.120824?z=16"
after lat,long values in your Uri
set z=1-23 range(1 to 23) and it will work.